# Start-Process does nothing in event action

Tags: powershell, pdf, adobe

I'm using:

```bash
$fsw = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher (Get-Location).Drive.Root, "*.pdf" -Property @{
    IncludeSubdirectories = $true;
    NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName'
}

Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Renamed -Action {
    $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
    Start-Process –FilePath $path –Verb Print -PassThru | %{sleep 5;$_} | Stop-Process
}
```

to try to watch for renamed PDFs (.tmp files getting renamed when a browser download completes) and use `Start-Process` to open the file with Adobe and print without the print dialog.  The `Start-Process` line comes from numerous other examples online, and works fine as a one-liner in PowerShell, but it doesn't seem to do anything inside the Renamed Event's `-Action`.  Is there something I'm missing, or doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.